# Google Search Console emailing "New Mobile Usability issue detected" but live test shows "Page is mobile friendly"

Tags: google, google-search-console, email, mobile, mobile-friendly-tool

I have a site with 20,000 URLs per language.   Each language is added as a separate property in Google Search Console.  This month Google started emailing me about each of the properties due to "New Mobile Usability issue(s) found".

[image]

The specific issues are one or both of:

- Text too small to read
- Clickable elements too close together

When I click on "Fix Mobile Usability issues" I find that there are usually one or two URLs out of 20,000 that have a problem.   When I live test those URLs, the live test reports "Page is mobile friendly."

[image]

Is this a bug in Google's mobile testing tool?

I run AdSense ads on the pages through DFP, could it be detecting temporary problems with certain ads?  (I thought AdSense ads were blocked from Googlebot, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Is this a bug in Google's mobile testing tool? - May be a bug also. Because I also faced the same issue while dealing with some of the websites.
As I checked those pages were Mobile Friendly.

As I observe running Adsense won't be the reason for that.

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one with this problem.   You don't have ads on your pages that have this problem?

Comment: Every few days I get a message like this from Google and as is stated above, I test the page from Google Webmaster Mobile usability test and it passes as mobile friendly, I'm not advertising with them - feels like harassment.

Comment: I am also having the exact same issue.