# Google mobile friendly tester cannot reproduce errors on device or Chrome

Tags: mobile-friendly-tool

I have a number of pages which are failing the Google mobile friendly tests.

When viewed in the [Mobile friendly tester](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly) two errors are reported:

> 1. Clickable elements too close together
> 2. **Content wider than screen**

It is this second issue "Content wider than screen" I'm having a problem with. If you inspect the page in Google Chrome -> Choose Google Pixel device, the content is scaled correctly to fit the viewport (411 pixels)

[image]

I cannot find a single element of the page which is wider than the viewport.

Another [testing tool here](https://www.seocentro.com/tools/seo/mobile-friendly.html) reports the actual error, which says:

> The page content is too wide for the viewport, forcing the user to scroll horizontally. Size the page content to the viewport to provide a better user experience.
>   **The page content is 1,092 CSS pixels wide, but the viewport is only 412 CSS pixels wide.**

Again I can't find which element(s) on the page are greater than 412 pixels wide.

Could this be a false positive?

Or could it be a latency issue? What if my server isn't serving CSS fast enough for the mobile tester?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I was getting emails about these two problems too, but when I used the live test at Google it reported no errors.   See [Google Search Console emailing “New Mobile Usability issue detected” but live test shows “Page is mobile friendly”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121402/google-search-console-emailing-new-mobile-usability-issue-detected-but-live-te)  Are you seeing the live test show the problems?

Comment: Yeah the live test was showing the problem. Updated with an answer - we resolved the issue (related to caching)

Answer (score 1):

This problem was resolved and was not a CSS issue or page layout issue, but a caching plugin [AutoOptimize](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) was combining Javascript and causing some scripts to run too late for the mobile tester to see the result.

So it was a false positive but resolved by tweaking caching settings.