# What does "Validation looking good" mean from Google Search Console's "fix mobile UX error?"

Tags: google-search-console, mobile

I had a page with "text too small" mobile UX error. Our dev guy fixed it, and I submitted it to validation with the idea that it will remove the "error" mark. I now have this report though:

[image]

I am clueless if the error still exists or not. Validation passed but the error is still there - anyone with experience in the new Search Console messages?

Comment: I submitted a validation on 3/17 and it now says "Validation passed":  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaGqy.png    I never saw the "looking good" message, mine said "pending" when I last checked it a couple days ago.    The clock icon beside "looking good" makes me think that it is still pending, but I'm not sure why it would sound so positive if that is the case.   What does "See Details" show?  Mine is now out of the "Pending" column and into the "Passed" column.

Comment: Incidentally, mine appears to be a false positive.   Google keeps emailing me that I have a handful of pages with mobile UX errors but when I "live test" them (or now submit them for verification) they pass without changes.   I asked about that here: [Google Search Console emailing “New Mobile Usability issue detected” but live test shows “Page is mobile friendly”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121402/google-search-console-emailing-new-mobile-usability-issue-detected-but-live-te)

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same situation but my error count is reduced by 8 numbers. I guess it means the errors are resolved and it will be removed from search console once those pages will be crawled.