# Google Search Console “Mobile Usability issues” but live test shows “Page is mobile friendly”

Tags: google, google-search-console, mobile, mobile-friendly-tool

Looking into a customers site that has been having issues with Mobile Usability issues in the google search console.

Specific issues are:

- Clickable elements too close together
- Text too small to read

and with a bit less frequency:

- Content wider than screen

When I **live test** any of the URLs that have failed, the live test reports "Page is mobile friendly."

[image: Page is mobile friendly]

If I **inspect** any of the URLs and then click **View crawled page** you can get to the **more info** tab where it shows (for example) that 67/88 resources couldn't be loaded.  Most are listed as **Other error**.

Two of the pages today are **Redirection error**, & both from cloudfront.net (caching error?)

This list is mostly images / fonts but almost always the css file is in that list, which would then cause these issues.

The images are served from cloudfront and the webserver.  Css is from cloudfront.  Fonts are cloudfront / google.

Even fails on fonts from google:

[image: Other error]

---

Back in march there was upwards of 300 pages with these issues, but now it is down to about ~20 that fail.

Here is the graph for **Clickable elements too close together**:

[image: Affected pages]

Initially was thinking it was happening on pages with more resources than others, but each re-test seems to be a different set of pages.

I think this is the same issues as: [Google Search Console emailing "New Mobile Usability issue detected" but live test shows "Page is mobile friendly"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121402/google-search-console-emailing-new-mobile-usability-issue-detected-but-live-te/123435#123435)

Just trying to provide more data to see if there is a solution to this.

Comment: This thread indicates it is an error related to Google's crawler and potentially independent of the webpage / server ?  https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/4786439

Comment: The "mobile usability" testing page seems to be very erratic. I am seeing different view of my page from their testing and from the Chrome mobile view in development tools.